# Are there any security concerns of making a CORS request from HTTP to HTTPS?

Tags: http, https, cors

I have a server that I have confirmed can only be accessed through HTTPS. Is there anything I should be worried about if a trusted website that uses HTTP makes a CORS request to the HTTPS endpoint?

Thank you ahead of time for your help.

Comment: Why don't you use https in all the webpages?

Comment: I just wanted to make sure there was a case for having HTTPS everywhere. I wasn't sure, because in previous posts I've seen people have been asking about making these requests and I didn't see a "word of warning" on making these kinds of requests. It didn't seem secure to me, and I thought I should ask. Thank you, Tom.

Comment: You're welcome. The real question is not anymore "why https" but "why http". If you don't have a real reason to use http, use https ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, it's insecure**: if an http webpage of your domain can read the answer of an https webpage of your domain, **an attacker can**, by modifying the http webpage.

Even if the user doesn't visit your website! An attacker car use any website using http to include an http iframe of your website, modify the content to force a CORS request to your https webpage and send the answer to the attacker.

"trusted website that uses HTTP":it may be "trusted" (whitelisted) by CORS, but **an http webpage CANNOT be trusted**.

**TL;DR: use https, everywhere, or you will make a mistake that weaken security.**

Comment: I feel like this might be an stupid question, but what's stopping an attacker from doing the same to an HTTPS webpage?

Comment: By "attacker", I mean somebody between a visitor and your server. It's trivial to modify http requests, and really hard to do it with https